# Do I need Xcode (and a Mac) to develop an Ionic app for iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cordova, ionic-framework

I wish to develop an [Ionic App](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_(mobile_app_framework)) for Android, iOS and Windows Store. I am currently using my HP Windows 10 laptop alongside [Cloud9](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud9_IDE) [IDE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment).

Do I need to purchase a Mac (old Mac mini, old Imac) to be able to use [Xcode](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) for creating/compiling the [iOS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS) app?

Comment: FYI: I am using an old mac mini 2010 (Code2Duo) for developing iOS cordova apps and it works quite well with additional ssd.

Answer (score 5):

The are some points you need to know.

*You need a Mac to create a Cordova vesion of you App?*

**Answer:** Theoretically no, because Phonegap (Adobes Cordova) has remote Builders that you can use to create a package of you App for IOS. But, this remote service is paid.

*So I should use Adobe Phonegap remote builder?*

**Answer:** I would not use. A remote automatically builder will never be as good as you control the actions of what is being created or maipulated on your App.

*So it's better to buy a mac?*

**Answer:** Yes.

*I will need an Iphone or Ipad device too?*

**Answer:** No. As mentioned before, you could test your App using XCode emulator (wich include Iphones, Ipads and more). Only buy an IPhone if you want to be sure that all features of your App is working (given that an Emulator will never be a real device).

**Good alternative:** You could create a Mac Virtual Machine and try to develop through that (if your Windows Machine is really good). *The problem:* It will be very difficult to test your App with a real IOS device using the virtual machine. We will basically work with XCode emulators.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, also you will need an apple developer account, and probable and iPhone / iPad for testing

Comment: Would a 2007 Imac running Snow Leopard work or a old Mac Mini do it perhaps? Then I can upgrade it to the latest El Capitan and access the latest XCode

Answer (score 0):

**No!** You can develop apps using Ionic Framework for Cordova/Phonegap, altough in order to publish the app on the AppStore you will need an Apple developer account.

@Del - No physical device is needed for testing an app. You can use the device simulator in xCode.

Comment: But to compile the app for submission to the AppStore I would need to do this using Xcode. This would mean I need to purchase a Mac would it not?

Comment: Phonegap compiles the apps and you do not need a Mac for compiling an app.

Comment: Just found this, check out Andrew's post who is very active in the Ionic community. It looks like I need a Mac for uploading https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-build-app-for-iphone-without-mac/19929/11

Answer (score 0):

No. XCode only runs on OS X, but it is possible to install OS X on a PC not sold by Apple if you select the right components, which is typically far less expensive. (This is known informally as a Hackintosh.)

This isn't officially supported and is not always straightforward; it also violates the OS X license agreement, so its legality may vary between jurisdictions.

You can find information on doing this at http://www.hackintosh.com and http://lifehacker.com/the-always-up-to-date-guide-to-building-a-hackintosh-o-5841604, among other sites.

Comment: I have a Snow Leopard official sealed disk and have had some success with it on Virtualbox. Can it be upgraded to El Capitan and will this be Ok license wise?

Answer (score 0):

VMWare with Mac Image works well.